# How to define syntax annotations in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to define valid quadruple ⊨ {P}c×c'{Q} of Hoare logic in Isabelle/HOL, where c and c' are commands and P and Q are assertions. Assertions are defined as :

```
type_synonym assn = "state × state ⇒ bool"
```

I have defined the valid quadruple as following:

```
definition 
rel_hoare_valid :: "assn ⇒ com × com ⇒ assn ⇒ bool" ("⊨ {(1_)}/ (_)/ {(1_)}" 50) 
where "⊨ {P}c×c'{Q} = ..."
```

... contains rest of the code, which is not relevant.

I know that the syntax annotation part

```
("⊨ {(1_)}/ (_)/ {(1_)}" 50)
```

is not correct, but I don't know how to fix it.

The error message is as following:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ set" and "_ × _"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  rel_hoare_valid P :: com × com ⇒ ((char list ⇒ int) × (char 
list ⇒ int) ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool
Operand:   c × c' :: (??'a × ??'b) set
```

Comment: What is the error you receive to make you say that it's not correct?

Comment: Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ set" and "_ × _"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

  Operator:  rel_hoare_valid P :: com × com ⇒ ((char list ⇒ int) × (char list ⇒ int) ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool  
  Operand:   c × c' :: (??'a × ??'b) set

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information :)

Comment: done, I added the error message ;)

Comment: This has been posted to the mailing list too: https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2017-June/msg00023.html